# How to apply std::is_convertible_v to a set of variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to check that if a list of arguments is convertible to `size_t` or not. I think maybe the `std::is_convertible_v` is the right tool from STL. Here is what I imagine it should be (which is wrong):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Args>
constexpr bool check_all_convertible ()
{
    return std::is_convertible_v<Args,size_t>;
}
```

I finally want to use the `check_all_convertible()` to enable another function:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<check_all_convertible<Args...>(), void> 
    some_function (Args... args) {}
```

## Question

- How can I use `std::is_convertible_v` for variadic arguments?
- Do you suggest a better approach from STL?

I appreciate any suggestion to improve the code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++20 solution (Yes!! We finally have concepts!!!):

```
#include <concepts>

auto some_function(std::convertible_to<std::size_t> auto ... args)
{
}
```

See it live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uUGCXu).

The `auto` is needed because the committee reasoned without it the declaration would deceptively look like a function (but it is a template). Bjarne thinks they will regret it down the line. Anyway we should get used to typing `auto` all the time because from now on we shouldn't write unconstrained templates.

For completeness here is the longer version (but I recommend the terse one):

```
template <std::convertible_to<std::size_t>... Args>
auto some_function2(Args... args)
{
}
```

And the longer longer version:

```
template <class... Args>
    requires (std::convertible_to<Args, std::size_t> && ...)
auto some_function3(Args... args)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I checked C++ standard support in GCC and it seems that concepts will appear in gcc 10.x. Did you tried to compile your answer with gcc 9.2 or shall I wait for next version of gcc?

Comment: It compiles with gcc trunk, but not with gcc 9.2. With clang, they don't have the `<concepts>` library yet, but if you use type_traits or if you define your own concept it compiles since clang 6

Comment: actually with clang the long version compiles with clang 9. For the terse one you need clang trunk. Older versions of clang use an older proposal for concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will make the code more readable than before.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a fold expression:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<Args,size_t> && ...)> 
some_function (Args... args) {}
```

Comment: Thanks to your solution, my code is more readable and simpler now. C++17 is Great!

Answer (score 1):

As I found out you have C++17 support, but in case of C++11/C++14 you can do following (maybe you will need it in the future):

```cpp
template<
    typename    To,
    typename    From
    typename... Rest
> constexpr bool is_converible_variadic_impl()
{
    return \
        std::is_convertible<From, To>::value && 
        is_converible_variadic_impl<To, Rest...>();
}

template<
    typename To,
    typename From
> constexpr bool is_converible_variadic_impl()
{
    return std::is_convertible<From, To>::value;
}

/*************************************************/

template<
    typename    To,
    typename... From
> struct is_convertible_variadic
   : std::integral_constant<bool, is_converible_variadic_impl<To, From...>()>
{ };

template<
    typename    To,
    typename... From
> constexpr bool is_convertible_variadic_v = is_convertible_variadic<To, From...>::value;
```

For `size_t` use it as in following example:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_variadic_v<size_t, Args...> > 
some_function (Args... args) {}
```

Maybe it is confusing to put "To" type in the beginning (mismatch with STL) of template parameters, but I think it is not such complicated task to fix it :)